# Calculating mean of certain list values in Python

Tags: python, list, mean

I've been trying to calculate the mean of the third, fourth and fifth values in each row of a .csv file, but my program will only calculate for the first row rather than for each row.
For example, this code:

```
file=open("file.csv", "r")
data=csv.reader(file)

data=[[row[0],row[1],eval(row[2]),eval(row[3]),eval(row[4])] for row in data]

from statistics import mean

numbers=[row[2],row[3],row[4]]
newdata=[[row[0],row[1],mean(numbers)] for row in data]
sort=sorted(newdata,key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)


for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline)

file.close()
```

...reads this file:

```
Phillip,Turner,1,4,10
Sarah,Connor,4,8,1
Alex,Grice,2,10,3
Cheesy,Wotsit,3,2,6
Chris,Mclaughlin,10,9,8
Alison,Humphries,4,2,6
```

and produces this:

```
['Phillip', 'Turner', 4.0]
['Sarah', 'Connor', 4.0]
['Alex', 'Grice', 4.0]
['Cheesy', 'Wotsit', 4.0]
['Chris', 'Mclaughlin', 4.0]
['Alison', 'Humphries', 4.0]
```

Comment: `newdata=[[row[0],row[1],mean(row[2:])] for row in data]`

Comment: where did you get the idea to use eval? Also is this more gcse exam stuff?

Comment: worked @Jkdc thank you - post it as an answer and I'll best answer it!

Comment: @gulliver you also have to convert each item that you want to find a mean of, to a numerical type (int or float). Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its not the mean of the first line, its the mean from the last. After the first list comprehension, row assumes the value of the last row, and when you use row[2] to create numbers list, you create a static list using the values from the last row.

You can correct that by making mean of the correct numbers:

```
file=open("file.csv", "r")
data=csv.reader(file)

data=[[row[0],row[1],eval(row[2]),eval(row[3]),eval(row[4])] for row in data]

from statistics import mean

newdata=[[row[0],row[1],mean([row[2],row[3],row[4]])] for row in data]
sort=sorted(newdata,key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)


for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline)

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
averages = []
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
  for row in reader:
    values = map(int, row[2:])
    averages.append(row + [sum(values) / float(len(values))])
for avg in sorted(averages,key=lambda x: x[-1]):
  print avg
```

prints

```
['Cheesy', 'Wotsit', '3', '2', '6', 3.6666666666666665]
['Alison', 'Humphries', '4', '2', '6', 4.0]
['Sarah', 'Connor', '4', '8', '1', 4.333333333333333]
['Phillip', 'Turner', '1', '4', '10', 5.0]
['Alex', 'Grice', '2', '10', '3', 5.0]
['Chris', 'Mclaughlin', '10', '9', '8', 9.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this `numbers=[row[2],row[3],row[4]]` for each row. Not just once. 
You could do:

```
In [511]: data = csv.reader(open('../a.csv'))

In [512]: x = [[row[0], row[1], np.mean(map(float, row[2:]))] for row in data]

In [513]: x
Out[513]: 
[['Phillip', 'Turner', 5.0],
 ['Sarah', 'Connor', 4.333333333333333],
 ['Alex', 'Grice', 5.0],
 ['Cheesy', 'Wotsit', 3.6666666666666665],
 ['Chris', 'Mclaughlin', 9.0],
 ['Alison', 'Humphries', 4.0]]

In [514]: sorted(x, key=lambda v: v[2], reverse=True)
Out[514]: 
[['Chris', 'Mclaughlin', 9.0],
 ['Phillip', 'Turner', 5.0],
 ['Alex', 'Grice', 5.0],
 ['Sarah', 'Connor', 4.333333333333333],
 ['Alison', 'Humphries', 4.0],
 ['Cheesy', 'Wotsit', 3.6666666666666665]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
with open('your_file') as f:
    for x in f:
        x = x.strip().split()
        print x + [sum(map(int,x[2:]))/float(len(x[2:]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

`newdata=[[row[0],row[1],mean(numbers)] for row in data]`

Should be

`newdata=[[row[0],row[1],mean(row[2:])] for row in data]`